# In C#, var.ToList() conversion to DateTime List takes much longer than var.ToList() to Double List

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, datetime

I have a pair of LINQ-to-SQL queries which I then convert a List of Doubles and a List of DateTimes, respectively.

```
var p1 = (from c in db.Datas
    where (c.Symbol == symbol && 
           c.Date >= startDT && 
           c.Date <= endDT)
    orderby c.Date
    select c.P);
var q1 = p1.ToList();


var p2 = (from c in db.Datas
    where (c.Symbol == symbol &&
           c.Date >= startDT &&
           c.Date <= endDT
           )
   orderby c.Date
   select c.Date);
var q2 = p2.ToList();
```

Both query results have the same number of elements.

The ToList() conversion for q1 takes ~0.03 seconds. The q2 ToList() conversion takes ~8.2 seconds. The database queries themselves take approximately the same amount of time. How can I make the second ToList() call faster?

Comment: How have you measured? I'm fairly sure that that is causing your "issue".

Comment: @TimSchmelter - DateTime.Now.Subtract(DateTimeBeforeConversion) after each conversion

Comment: So the first problem is that you're using the wrong tool to measure elapsed time. Use the `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` class. Then come back with the new values. But i suspect that you're also didn't change `DateTimeBeforeConversion` after the first `ToList`.

Comment: You are not measuring the conversion you are also measuring the SQL Execution.

Comment: @Ralf: Yes, but that should not cause  different execution times since both select the same records, just different columns.

Comment: Different Selects Lists will likely result in different Execution Plans on the DB server. For example P in the first Query might be part of the used index while Date in the second is not. An extra table lookup would then be needed by the database.

Comment: @Ralf To clarify, timings are based on start-stop commands surrounding the var qx = px.ToList() lines, not inclusive of the SQL queries. Queries were included to provide context.

Comment: The Sql will be executed when ToList() is called. Its called deffered execution.

Comment: By the way shouldn't it be p1/p2.ToList() and not p.ToList()?

Comment: @Ralf Ah thanks, fixed now. Original code was from two separate functions, had to change variable names a bit... verifying Stopwatch timings...

Comment: Stopwatch timings: p1/q1: 0.179 sec. p2/q2: 8.228 sec

Comment: @JackHuang Read @ralf's comment again - you are not measuring _just_ the creation of a list.  You are measuring the actual execution of the underlying SQL Statement.  Before then `p1` and `p2` are just definitions of a query - not until `ToList` is called is the query actually executed on the server.

Comment: @DStanley The source DB table is indexed on Date, Symbol, and Date+Symbol. Given same source table & the same record count, could the Date query be that much slower than the P query?

Comment: Might sound unlikely yes but you will only know if you check it on the database.

Comment: Could you do a .ToString() on each p1 and p2 so we can see the generated queries? With out seeing the database it is hard to tell.  There could be cached results for the doubles or the date time query may be doing extra lookups or scans that we can't see.  Comparing the generated queries would be a good first step.  (as a note, linq-to-SQL has several really stupid query generation bugs that will most probably never be fixed.)

Comment: @Ralf Ah, that did it. SQL is showing vastly different execution times for the underlying queries. Thanks!